Repair hangs, returns validation error "Failed creating a merkle tree"
Cassandra 3.10, nodetool repair -pr on all hosts, only one host has validation error so how do I fix it ?
On all 12 hosts, we ran
nodetool repair -pr
It completed fine on 11 nodes but one node return validation error.
Console Output of  nodetool repair -pr  shows following
Console output  ( output of nodetool repair -pr on host xx-xxx-xx-99 )
ERROR [ValidationExecutor:17] 2024-08-18 06:04:32,157 Validator.java:268 - Failed creating a merkle tree for [repair
#6743f7b1-5d27-11ef-a1ea-73dd38b566d3 on ncl/vod_content_reprocess, [(1727736060172993051,1736912528324321100], (-4483939241352143448,-4479269428852420951], (-6428569111890689205,-6427615614052953911], (6932277009776771909,6936540514239532742], (-3394415842952795259,-3392661459066787345], (-8757357875698439289,-8756441558319424387], (6382634559972203860,6384252000363136344], (1765421538791911802,1773315068909157661], (8952780146872479351,8958935473061678116], (1220849725974638095,1221362531539162734], (-6895633169703087366,-6892388575530810237], (5740884132146258663,5751180500813920396], (-2619608355693184567,-2609362512909603522], (7448798786146498113,7450425414450981534], (-5167637286414616645,-5143394249380792294], (-8898667291742040850,-8894251459383546501]]], /XX.XXX.XX.99 (see log for details)

system.log  IP ending with .195

[2024-08-18 06:04:32,163] Repair session
6743f7b1-5d27-11ef-a1ea-73dd38b566d3 for range
[(1727736060172993051,1736912528324321100],
(-4483939241352143448,-4479269428852420951],
(-6428569111890689205,-6427615614052953911],
(6932277009776771909,6936540514239532742],
(-3394415842952795259,-3392661459066787345],
(-8757357875698439289,-8756441558319424387],
(6382634559972203860,6384252000363136344],
(1765421538791911802,1773315068909157661],
(8952780146872479351,8958935473061678116],
(1220849725974638095,1221362531539162734],
(-6895633169703087366,-6892388575530810237],
(5740884132146258663,5751180500813920396],
(-2619608355693184567,-2609362512909603522],
(7448798786146498113,7450425414450981534],
(-5167637286414616645,-5143394249380792294],
(-8898667291742040850,-8894251459383546501]] failed with error [repair
#6743f7b1-5d27-11ef-a1ea-73dd38b566d3 on ncl/vod_content_reprocess, [(1727736060172993051,1736912528324321100],
(-4483939241352143448,-4479269428852420951],
(-6428569111890689205,-6427615614052953911],
(6932277009776771909,6936540514239532742],
(-3394415842952795259,-3392661459066787345],
(-8757357875698439289,-8756441558319424387],
(6382634559972203860,6384252000363136344],
(1765421538791911802,1773315068909157661],
(8952780146872479351,8958935473061678116],
(1220849725974638095,1221362531539162734],
(-6895633169703087366,-6892388575530810237],
(5740884132146258663,5751180500813920396],
(-2619608355693184567,-2609362512909603522],
(7448798786146498113,7450425414450981534],
(-5167637286414616645,-5143394249380792294],
(-8898667291742040850,-8894251459383546501]]] Validation failed in
/XX.XXX.XX.195 (progress: 7%)

system.log
Log /XX.XXX.XX.99

INFO  [RepairJobTask:3] 2024-08-18 06:04:32,141 RepairJob.java:143 -
[repair #6743f7b1-5d27-11ef-a1ea-73dd38b566d3] linear_event is fully
synced INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2024-08-18 06:04:32,158
RepairSession.java:180 - [repair
#6743f7b1-5d27-11ef-a1ea-73dd38b566d3] Received merkle tree for vod_content_reprocess from /10.204.72.195 INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1]
2024-08-18 06:04:32,159 RepairSession.java:180 - [repair
#6743f7b1-5d27-11ef-a1ea-73dd38b566d3] Received merkle tree for vod_content_reprocess from /10.204.72.68 WARN  [RepairJobTask:7]
2024-08-18 06:04:32,159 RepairJob.java:153 - [repair
#6743f7b1-5d27-11ef-a1ea-73dd38b566d3] vod_content_reprocess sync failed INFO  [Repair#5:2] 2024-08-18 06:04:32,159 RepairJob.java:172 -
[repair #6743f7b1-5d27-11ef-a1ea-73dd38b566d3] Requesting merkle trees
for preference_lookuplog (to [/10.204.72.68, /10.204.72.195,
/10.204.73.99]) ERROR [Repair#5:1] 2024-08-18 06:04:32,159
CassandraDaemon.java:229 - Exception in thread Thread[Repair#5:1,5,RMI
Runtime]
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException:
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.RepairException: [repair
#6743f7b1-5d27-11ef-a1ea-73dd38b566d3 on ncl/vod_content_reprocess, [(1727736060172993051,1736912528324321100],
(-4483939241352143448,-4479269428852420951],
(-6428569111890689205,-6427615614052953911],
(6932277009776771909,6936540514239532742],
(-3394415842952795259,-3392661459066787345],
(-8757357875698439289,-8756441558319424387],
(6382634559972203860,6384252000363136344],
(1765421538791911802,1773315068909157661],
(8952780146872479351,8958935473061678116],
(1220849725974638095,1221362531539162734],
(-6895633169703087366,-6892388575530810237],
(5740884132146258663,5751180500813920396],
(-2619608355693184567,-2609362512909603522],
(7448798786146498113,7450425414450981534],
(-5167637286414616645,-5143394249380792294],
(-8898667291742040850,-8894251459383546501]]] Validation failed in
/XX.XXX.XX.195
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.wrapAndThrowUnchecked(Futures.java:1525)
~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.getUnchecked(Futures.java:1511)
~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairJob.run(RepairJob.java:160)
~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
~[na:1.8.0_162]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
~[na:1.8.0_162]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:79)
~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_162] Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.RepairException: [repair
#6743f7b1-5d27-11ef-a1ea-73dd38b566d3 on ncl/vod_content_reprocess, [(1727736060172993051,1736912528324321100],
(-4483939241352143448,-4479269428852420951],
(-6428569111890689205,-6427615614052953911],
(6932277009776771909,6936540514239532742],
(-3394415842952795259,-3392661459066787345],
(-8757357875698439289,-8756441558319424387],
(6382634559972203860,6384252000363136344],
(1765421538791911802,1773315068909157661],
(8952780146872479351,8958935473061678116],
(1220849725974638095,1221362531539162734],
(-6895633169703087366,-6892388575530810237],
(5740884132146258663,5751180500813920396],
(-2619608355693184567,-2609362512909603522],
(7448798786146498113,7450425414450981534],
(-5167637286414616645,-5143394249380792294],
(-8898667291742040850,-8894251459383546501]]] Validation failed in
/10.204.72.195
at org.apache.cassandra.repair.ValidationTask.treesReceived(ValidationTask.java:64)
~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairSession.validationComplete(RepairSession.java:182)
~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.ActiveRepairService.handleMessage(ActiveRepairService.java:481)
~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairMessageVerbHandler.doVerb(RepairMessageVerbHandler.java:162)
~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:66)
~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
~[na:1.8.0_162]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
... 4 common frames omitted

I ran on range which were mentioned in error so all other ran fine except this one
 nodetool repair -st -3394415842952795259 -et -3392661459066787345 ncl vod_content_reprocess  
[2024-08-18 07:45:09,732] Starting repair command #31 (cb4dad10-5d35-11ef-97df-236166759c04), repairing keyspace ncl with repair options (parallelism: parallel, primary range: false, incremental: true, job threads: 1, ColumnFamilies: [vod_content_reprocess], dataCenters: [], hosts: [], # of ranges: 1, pull repair: false)
[2024-08-18 07:45:09,762] Repair session cb4f81d0-5d35-11ef-97df-236166759c04 for range [(-3394415842952795259,-3392661459066787345]] failed with error [repair #cb4f81d0-5d35-11ef-97df-236166759c04 on ncl/vod_content_reprocess, [(-3394415842952795259,-3392661459066787345]]] Validation failed in /10.204.72.195 (progress: 100%)
[2024-08-18 07:45:09,763] Some repair failed
[2024-08-18 07:45:09,765] Repair command #31 finished in 0 seconds
error: Repair job has failed with the error message: [2024-08-18 07:45:09,763] Some repair failed
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.RuntimeException: Repair job has failed with the error message: [2024-08-18 07:45:09,763] Some repair failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.RepairRunner.progress(RepairRunner.java:116)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.progress.jmx.JMXNotificationProgressListener.handleNotification(JMXNotificationProgressListener.java:77)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.dispatchNotification(ClientNotifForwarder.java:583)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.doRun(ClientNotifForwarder.java:533)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.run(ClientNotifForwarder.java:452)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$LinearExecutor$1.run(ClientNotifForwarder.java:108)


Thanks for posting on Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Validation compactions (operation for creating the merkle tree on a replica) can fail for various reasons.
Unfortunately you didn't provide sufficient detail in your question to give an indication of what the problem was other than the validation failed.
You will need to review the logs on the replica indicated in the error where the validation failed for clues. For example, this error message indicates that you need to check the logs on node 10.204.73.99 for details of the failure:
ERROR [ValidationExecutor:160] 2024-08-16 00:28:23,279 Validator.java:268 - \
  Failed creating a merkle tree for [repair #75a50bf0-5b65-11ef-8144-d785813ce287 on ncl/vod_content_reprocess, [...], \
  /10.204.73.99 (see log for details)

As a side note, running a repair with the partitioner range option (-pr) is more efficient than a regular full repair because only the range(s) for which the node is the primary owner will get repaired. If you are interested, Jeremiah Jordan explains it in detail on his blog post Apache Cassandra Maintenance and Repair. Cheers!

Ramirez, I have updated question with logs.

I was able to resolve issue. Issue were some data files for vod_content_reprocess-4752923014a011ed9ebfdfadb9ed3327 table which had very old time stamp. Once I moved/deleted these data files to other backup location and ran repair, it worked fine. So in nutshell some old left over datafiles were causing issue. notetool compact on the problem node also said sst table is corrupt. It looks like nodetool repair didn't complain about corrupt sst table but nodetool compact did mention about sst datafile corruption.
